# InfluxDB2 "Unauthorized" issue when sending data point to influxdb via apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, authorization, influxdb-2

I created a "write" token for influxDB 2.71 via the InfluxDB Web UI where I ticked on only the target bucket for a write operation I want to perform. In addition to that I already created a admin-token as well via the UI.

Then, I send Influx points via an Apache Camel producer. This works fine if I use the admin token. However, when I use the write token, I get an error message in the Java console:

```
com.influxdb.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: HTTP status code: 401; Message: write:orgs is unauthorized
```

Besides the token, which is kept in an application.yml file, the code is exactly the same...